# Is it possible to get credentials from Vault in Jenkins file ?

Tags: git, jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I want store ssh keys to git in HashiCorp Vault, then in my Jenkins file i want to get my key and use it to check out and commit to repository, is it possible or should i go traditional way, Define credentials in Jenkins and then use it. Purpose of such question is because i want to keep all secret info in Vault

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the [Hashicorp Vault Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HashiCorp+Vault+Plugin) - which can allow you access secrets in a Jenkinsfile [as shown here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/hashicorp-vault-plugin#usage-via-jenkinsfile):

```
node {
  // define the secrets and the env variables
  def secrets = [
      [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/testing', secretValues: [
          [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'testing', vaultKey: 'value_one'],
          [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'testing_again', vaultKey: 'value_two']]],
      [$class: 'VaultSecret', path: 'secret/another_test', secretValues: [
          [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'another_test', vaultKey: 'value']]]
  ]

  // optional configuration, if you do not provide this the next higher configuration
  // (e.g. folder or global) will be used
  def configuration = [$class: 'VaultConfiguration',
                       vaultUrl: 'http://my-very-other-vault-url.com',
                       vaultCredentialId: 'my-vault-cred-id']

  // inside this block your credentials will be available as env variables
  wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', configuration: configuration, vaultSecrets: secrets]) {
      sh 'echo $testing'
      sh 'echo $testing_again'
      sh 'echo $another_test'
  }
}
```

Comment: teakvinyl, thank you for answer ,but that is not what i need, credentials should be not known on Jenkins setup step, when project builds i want get ssh key from Vault and then check out and commit to git with those credentials(in traditional way we use ID of predefined credentials ) but i want to get newly retrieved credentials from Vault.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that I misunderstood you. Just to clarify, what do you mean when you say "credentials should be not known on Jenkins setup step"?

Comment: I mean that they shouldn't be predefined

Comment: The vault credential shouldn't be predefined? Or the ssh keys?

Comment: SSH Key should be stored in Vault, then i want get SSH key in Jenkins file, and then use it in connection to git repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the same vault jenkins plugin.

1. Create ssh as secret in vault and create AppRole for jenkins in vault with read,list access policies. You should now have the RoleId and secretId for the AppRole.
2. In jenkins, create a vault AppRole credential with RoleId and SecretId.
3. In the pipeline use withVault()

```
withVault(configuration: [timeout: 60, vaultCredentialId: '<ur vault credential>', vaultUrl: '<ur vault URL>'], vaultSecrets: [[path: 'secret/<ur secret ssh path>', secretValues: [[vaultKey: '<ur key of ssh>']]]]) {
              //use as env.<<ur key of ssh>>
           }
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/hashicorp-vault-plugin